# How can I tell if a function object was made with a fat arrow expression?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a function that takes an object as an argument, and does things with the data stored in that object. Some of what I want to do involves functions in that object. I want to bind most of them to various objects, but that won't work for any functions made with [fat arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions). So, I want to do something different with them. How can I tell them apart?

Note: I am aware that normal functions have a prototype but ones made by fat arrow syntax don't, but I can't use that because functions made with [method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Method_definition_syntax) also don't have a prototype, but they can be bound so I want to treat them like other functions.

Comment: how about using `toString` method of the function and checking the `=>` existence?

Comment: Arrow functions are just functions. Don't try to treat them differently. If they don't care about the context that you're passing, it's not your concern.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Function#toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) to check the function's source code and see if it was defined as an arrow function.

```
const foo = () => {};
const fooStr = Function.prototype.toString.call(foo);
const isArrow = fooStr.includes(') => {');
```

Note that the above implementation is probably too naive for most use cases, as it has a few false positives and negatives. For starters, `isArrow` will be `true` if `foo` were a normal function that contained an arrow function (or otherwise had that particular string anywhere inside of it, such as a comment, etc.)

We can improve upon this by trying to match the head of the function definition in particular. Below, I do this by searching for the first occurrence of a curly brace `{`, which is common to both arrow and non-arrow functions.

```
const foo = () => {};
const fooStr = Function.prototype.toString.call(foo);
const curlyIndex = fooStr.indexOf('{');
const head = fooStr.substring(0, Math.max(curlyIndex, 0));
const isArrow = head.endsWith(') => {');
```

Unfortunately for us, both the round and curly braces are actually optional for arrow functions and they don't even need any whitespace. So ideally we need something that works when `foo` is `x=>x`, for example.

```
const foo = x=>x;
const fooStr = Function.prototype.toString.call(foo);
const curlyIndex = fooStr.indexOf('{');
let isArrow = true;
if (curlyIndex >= 0) {
    const head = fooStr.substring(0, curlyIndex);
    isArrow = head.replace(/\s/g, '').endsWith('=>{');
}
```

The above implementation is half-way decent, but it still has a false negative when `foo` is something like `x => x + '{'`. There are other gotchas, so don't think it ends there. String analysis is hard, especially when syntax is optional.

You could use a library like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/), [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn), or [Cherow](https://github.com/cherow/cherow), to parse the string and more perfectly identify whether the code is an arrow function, but this may be overkill for you.

To give you an idea of what that would look like, below is the output from the [Cherow demo](https://cherow.github.io/cherow/) when I input an empty arrow function:

```
{
    "type": "Program",
    "sourceType": "script",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ExpressionStatement",
            "expression": {
                "type": "ArrowFunctionExpression",
                "body": {
                    "type": "BlockStatement",
                    "body": []
                },
                "params": [],
                "id": null,
                "async": false,
                "generator": false,
                "expression": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```